# Differential equation with step function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm studying classical mechanics and differential equations are, of course, central. Problem is we never had a class for ODE (except for the very basics) and we have to study ODE on our own. So I'm really confused and a beginner in the topic, so don't go with advanced stuff with me please. I need some clear explanation, even without calculations.

My teacher put this Cauchy Problem in a test:
\begin{equation}
\ddot{x}+\omega^2x=f(t)\quad\text{where }f(t)=\begin{cases}f_0 & 0 \le t \le \frac{2\pi}{\omega}\\
0 & otherwise\\ \end{cases}\end{equation}
with $x(0)=\dot{x(0)}=0$ s initial conditions.

So I don't know what to do exactly because my book says that the existence and uniqueness of the solution is guaranteed if the function is Lipschitzian, and my $f(t)$ is not. Plus I don't understand how to "link" the solutions together in the general case.
I tried to solve them separately, so for my time interval I got:
\begin{equation}
\phi_1(t)=c_1cos(\omega t)+c_2sin(\omega t)+\frac{f_0}{\omega^2}
\end{equation}
and otherwise my solution is
\begin{equation}
\phi_2(t)=c_3cos(\omega t)+c_4sin(\omega t)
\end{equation}
So if they were two separate equations I would know how to solve them but in this case in my head everything is mixed up because I can't apply my initial conditions in $\phi_2$ (the instant t=0 is not in this "otherwise" interval). I can only put my Cauchy conditions in $\phi_1$ so that my result is:
\begin{equation}
\phi_1(t)=\frac{f_0}{\omega^2}(1-cos(\omega t))
\end{equation}
but that's what I would do without the other "otherwise" interval. I don't understand how to find $c_3$ and $c_4$ to get my piecewise solution. My trip on the internet resulted in confusing me even more. Can someone help? I know maybe this is a stupid question for you, but I just need someone to guide me, this is a complex argument and I'm finding this DIY really difficult.

Comment: Systems like these are handled better through the methods of Laplace Transformations, Most ODE books I know of have full sections on this. It is also helpful to write your right hand side in terms of the Heaviside step function, in your case $$ f_0\left(\theta{(t)} - \theta{\left(t - \frac{2\pi}{\omega}\right)}\right) $$ which switches on to a constant value of $f_0$ after $t=0$ then turns off when $t > \frac{2\pi}{\omega}$

Comment: Can you recommend me a good ODE book? I'm currently studying on a good italian book but it's about general analysis, so it doesn't explain these cases with a piecewise function.

Comment: And also... ok, I get it. I have to "Heaviside" my function. Can I then use the Lagrange method of parameters variation? I mean, where my particular solution is $\phi(t)=W(t)c(t)$ and I have to find c(t) by calculating the integral : \begin{equation}c(t)=\int_{\tau}^{t}W^{-1}(s)b(s)\,ds\end{equation}

Comment: As far as books go I'm not to familiar with most titles as my school basically made a copy for us so I don't really have any recommendations on hand. The Heaviside step function is a convenient way to rewrite the right-hand side as a single function, though it will still be far easier to attack it by Laplace methods than anything else. It is possible to solve through other methods, personally I myself wrote down a solution using the Laplace method on some scrap paper